# Number of Partitions of  No Part Appears Exactly Once

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

So I am having a little trouble here. The question is

"Let $r_n$ be the Number of Partitions of $n$ No Part Appears Exactly Once. Find the generating function."

I realize there is already an answer here, giving the generating function. But I don't understand how this person got the generating function. The answer can be found:

[Number of Partitions of $n$ No Part Appears Exactly Once Equals to $n$ Partitioned into 0,2 ,3 or 4 (Mod 6 )](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536114/number-of-partitions-of-n-no-part-appears-exactly-once-equals-to-n-partition)

But, it is somewhat asserted without showing this. I also am having some trouble finding some resources online as well. So, usually I would like to find some type of recurrence but I don't think that would be efficient in this case. So I am a little confused. Furthermore, this isn't a homework question. This is an old qual question I found.

Comment: This is the [OEIS sequence A007690](https://oeis.org/A007690) . The sequence entry has some good information.

Comment: Do you understand why the generating function for $p_n$, the number of partitions of $n$ (with no restrictions), is
$$
(1+q+q^2+\dots)(1+q^2+q^4+\dots)(1+q^3+q^6+\dots)\dots?
$$

Comment: Hey, Mike I am a little sketchy about this. After some work, and a little bit of googling, I found that specific generating you mentioned. I think that's why I am having trouble. I don't quite understand why that's the generating function. I mean I have thought it about throughout the night and I don't get it yet.

Comment: @E.C. When expanding out that product, you choose one term from each factor. The choice of term from $(1+q+q^2+\dots)$ determines the number of parts equal to $1$ in the corresponding partition; for example, choosing $q^7$ means there are $7$ parts equal to $1$. Similarly, the summand in $(1+q^2+q^4+\dots)$ determines the number of parts equal to $2$, etc. For some more detail, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1323854/177399).

Answer (score 1):

> I realize there is already an answer here, giving the generating function. But I don't understand how this person got the generating function.

It might help to add some variables to the generating function:

$((z_1x)^0 + (z_1x)^2 + (z_1x)^3 + \cdots)
 ((z_2x^2)^0 + (z_2x^2)^2 + (z_2x^2)^3 + \cdots)
 ((z_3x^3)^0 + (z_3x^3)^2 + (z_3x^3)^3 + \cdots) \cdots \\
= (1 + (z_1x)^2 + (z_1x)^3 + \cdots)
 (1 + (z_2x^2)^2 + (z_2x^2)^3 + \cdots)
 (1 + (z_3x^3)^2 + (z_3x^3)^3 + \cdots) \cdots$

So, for example, we have a term $(z_1x)^3 (z_3x^3)^2 = z_1{}^3 z_3{}^2 x^9$ corresponding to the partition $1 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 3 = 9$.

Now set all of the $z_i$ to $1$ to get the univariate generating function.

Then we can express it more elegantly using $\prod$ notation and the well-known expression for a geometric sum: $$\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 + (x^i)^2 + (x^i)^3 + \cdots)
&=& \prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1 + (x^i)^2 \frac{1}{1 - x^i}\right) \\
&=& \prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1 +  \frac{x^{2i}}{1 - x^i}\right) \\
&=& \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1 - x^i + x^{2i}}{1 - x^i} \\
&=& \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(1 - x^i + x^{2i})(1+x^i)}{(1 - x^i)(1+x^i)} \\
&=& \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1 + x^{3i}}{1 - x^{2i}} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

> So, usually I would like to find some type of recurrence but I don't think that would be efficient in this case.

Quite a lot of partition-related sequences have nice recurrences, essentially all due to Euler's pentagonal theorem (and its generalisation, Jacobi's triple product).

Euler's theorem is $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - x^n) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{k(3k \pm 1)/2}$$

This is useful because the [partition numbers](//oeis.org/A000041) $P(n)$ have g.f $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1 - x^n}$, or in other words $$\frac{1}{\sum_n P(n) x^n} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{k(3k \pm 1)/2}$$ which rearranges to $$\sum_n P(n) x^n = 1 - \left(\sum_n P(n) x^n\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{k(3k \pm 1)/2}\right)$$ and gives rise to the famous recurrence $$P(n) = P(n-1) + P(n-2) - P(n-5) - P(n-7) + \cdots$$

Now, [partitions into distinct parts](//oeis.org/A000009), $Q(n)$, have g.f. $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + x^n)$ and various recurrences: $$\begin{eqnarray}
Q(n) &=& (-1)^j \left[j \in \mathbb{N}, n = \frac{j(3j\pm 1)}{2}\right] - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor} (-1)^k Q(n - k^2) \\
&=& P(n) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k P(n - k(3k \pm 1)) \\
&=& (-1)^j [j \in \mathbb{N}, n = j(3j\pm1)] - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k Q\left(n - \frac{k(3k \pm 1)}{2} \right)
\end{eqnarray}$$ where $[\textrm{expr}]$ is an Iverson bracket, evaluating to $1$ if the expression is true and $0$ otherwise. The first two recurrences are in OEIS; the third I derived, but is probably not original.

The point of bringing up $Q$ is that our generating function of interest is a product of an inflated version of $Q$'s generating function and an inflated version of $P$'s generating function. I'm going to call it $A$ for "At least two". Then $$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty A(n) x^n &=& \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1 + x^{3i}}{1 - x^{2i}} \\
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty A(n) x^n\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - x^{2i})\right) &=& \prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 + x^{3i}) \\
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty A(n) x^n\right)\left(1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{k(3k \pm 1)}\right) &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty Q(k)x^{3k} \\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty A(n) x^n &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty Q(k)x^{3k} - \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty A(j) x^j\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{k(3k \pm 1)}\right) \\
A(n) &=& Q(\tfrac{n}{3}) [\tfrac{n}{3} \in \mathbb{N}] - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k A(n - k(3k \pm 1))
\end{eqnarray}$$